# file_get_contents returning null when sending request from unity

Tags: c#, php

I am handling post request data in PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");


    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    print $data;

    if(empty($data)){
        echo "\n data is empty";
    }
```

And sending data from C#:

```
string postData = JsonUtility.ToJson(correction);
        Debug.Log(postData);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(CorrectionMarkerAPIPaths.pathCorrectionCreate, postData))
        {
            www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            yield return www.Send();
            if (www.isError)
            {
                Debug.Log("Correction create failed with error : " + www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Correction created sucesful with message"+ www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
```

But on the server side, i am getting error that `$data` is empty

Comment: check result of `file_get_contents("php://input")`. maybe your request is not json.

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: put `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` befor of `$data = ....` line

Comment: Yeah it is empty when doing request from C# but it is correct in POSTMAN

Comment: so i think you request is not put. try this `var_dump($_POST);`. if this request is empty you must check your client.

Comment: $_Post is empty in postman. but i am sending postdata in json body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204526/discussion-between-ttrasn-and-muhammad-faizan-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who comes to this question:

From conversation we had. `unity` sends request as `urlencoded`. The [UnityWebRequest.Post](http://Form%20body%20data.%20Will%20be%20URLEncoded%20prior%20to%20transmission.) send urlencoded data:

1. `uri`   The target URI to which form data will be transmitted.
2. `postData`  Form body data. Will be URLEncoded prior to transmission.

to decode data in `PHP`.

```
$request = file_get_contents("php://input");
$decoded = urldecode($request);
```

to parse json to object:

```
$data = json_decode($decoded);
```

to get attribute of json.

```
$data->{attribute};
```