# How to get the JSON content of a HTTP Post request?

Tags: c#, json, laravel, http, unity-game-engine

I want to send a JSON file from my Unity application to my Laravel backend. It seems there is something wrong with my post request but I can't figure out what it is.

## Sending the request using Unity

```
public void SendRequest()
        {
            // serializable struct
            OfferData data = new OfferData(OfferSize.JUMBO, OfferType.AD, 50, 10);

            StartCoroutine(RequestHandler.Post(API_URL + "shop/store", JsonUtility.ToJson(data), (response) =>
            {
                if (response == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // success
                Debug.Log(response);
            }));
        }
```

The JSON:

```
{
"size":3,
"type":1,
"gold":50,
"gems":10
}
```

The post function in the RequestHandler:

```
public static IEnumerator Post(string uri, string data, Action<string> response)
        {
            UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, data);
            webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Error(webRequest.error);
                response(null);
            }
            else
            {
                response(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
```

If I'm sending the **UnityWebRequest** with Laravel will send a success response, however, the printed array (see below) is just empty. Laravel can not encode the JSON.

## Receiving the request in Laravel

This is where the HTTP Post request is being accessed in my controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Log::debug($request->json()->all());
}
```

Which produces the expected result when using Postman:

```
array ('size' => 3, 'type' => 1, 'gold' => 50, 'gems' => 10)
```

Sending a similar request with the same JSON using Unity:

```
array ()
```

When I use `$request->getContent()` I can actually see my data. Why is the array empty?

### Successful request header

The request header when sent from Postman:

```
{
"content-type": "application/json",
"user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.21.0",
"accept": "*/*",
"cache-control": "no-cache",
"postman-token": "d8f323fc-f2c8-49b8-a023-2955122fa20e",
"host": "127.0.0.1:8000",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"content-length": "119",
"cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkRyU1RqSkppcVdyUmpuVHI2Ym55XC9RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImQrc1QrOTcyWE1GSXM3SGQrVlBsTG1lZ0dXd1FCQlRPellTQm83Z0FkWFc0UktjUW9PNHRqS3B3Z2Rya1ZZS2IiLCJtYWMiOiIxMmNlZTFiODc2MTlmNmVhYjI3ZGI1MTQ1NTM2MGFjODQ4YjZhNzdlMmM4NWQwM2NiYzk1MjkzYzNiYjBmNTA5In0%3D; recludo_session=eyJpdiI6ImFLcUdCdU1WU2JzazNEaEFyaGoxbnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT1VtNzl4XC9HMW5reTdKUGNDdlBXMVdLK3hMNFR3Q2JxMzA1RVY3NWdVdmV5akJhbnBKeU9YdU5JSmdPdGYyNWUiLCJtYWMiOiI4MWJjOGVhMTcxNDI3M2VjNTU0MDc3NmNkZDU0NjZlMzhmYWI1MjRlZGNlZjhhNGEyNmNjMmY3YThiMzAyODNhIn0%3D",
"connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

### Faulty request header

The request header when sent from Unity:

```
{
"host": "127.0.0.1:8000",
"user-agent": "UnityPlayer/2019.2.8f1 (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.52.0-DEV)",
"accept": "*/*",
"accept-encoding": "deflate, gzip",
"cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlJhZE52emU1Z3hYUnVOWmtMbEdZa0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibkdabkhZVnM1ZUYwSklvMzYrSHVLQ0Q5Y2NvRlVTMEhJOHpqMGFCSEZLZVQwd2NnT3NrUmNrXC9cL2Z4XC92M0J0QSIsIm1hYyI6Ijg4ZDUwZDQ4MWQ3OWM3ZjNlOTcxOWE3NzMxYjI1MmQ3NGQ2YzgwMWQ2MDE2YTQ5NTI3NWQ3MTg2ODM4NjMxY2UifQ%3D%3D; recludo_session=eyJpdiI6InoyMktDN3ByR1hYR0tHWCtvdmhOckE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiamZJVnlDbVYwZkdBU1wvMXhMeG1sWU5LdDY0d0NnQ0VucE1OK05UNDhUOG1Ya2o5ZUJIcFdaSktuakcrQjJqN1QiLCJtYWMiOiI1YTc5YTE5NDNhNjY5NWRlYzlmMDlkOGIyMWRiYTAzYzMwZTkwNzAzYjBhNTA2OGViOTUyOTlkYzMzYWJlMjA3In0%3D",
"content-type": "application/json",
"x-unity-version": "2019.2.8f1",
"content-length": "215"
}
```

What am I missing? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: So what exactly is happening when doing it from Unity? Could you add the received output for that? Also please add how and what exactly you pass the json `data` to the method

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your comment! I've added the code how I pass and serialize the data. When I print the received request with `$request->getContent()` I can see that my data is actually here even though my array is empty!!

Comment: Please add: What is an `OfferData`. How does your JSON look like in Unity (`Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true));`)?

Comment: @derHugo I added the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why it doesn't work out of the box but I figured out how to fix this issue.

Add a raw upload handler to the **UnityWebRequest**:

```
UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, data);

// Fix: Add upload handler and pass json as bytes array
webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

The JSON data can now be resolved correctly by Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian Feistl's answer was the way to go for me, but instead of setting the "Content-Type" for the whole request as "application/json", it would only work if I set it for the uploadHandler:

```
webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
webRequest.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/json";
```

Experimenting with Postman, I found out that the "Content-Length" header is also necessary for this request (at least in my case) and I think that the uploadHandler helps in that regard too, as it sets the content in bytes, therefore the length as well. This is only speculation, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) send `urlencoded` data like

1. `uri` The target URI to which form data will be transmitted.
2. `postData` Form body data. Will be **URLEncoded** prior to transmission.

you should need to decode the content using [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method in php. Like

```
$decoded = urldecode($request);
```

to parse json to object:

```
$data = json_decode($decoded);
```

to get attribute of json.

```
$data->{attribute};
```

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work for me. Also I don't think that would be necessary because Laravel should be able to detect the json on its own. It works perfectly fine using Postman ...

Comment: Maybe it will helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404046/file-get-contents-returning-null-when-sending-request-from-unity