# HTTP Method Not Allowed in REST API Post

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, http-post

I am using UnityWebRequest to POST a string on the JSON that is accessible online. Unfortunately I am getting `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` error in Unity. It is definitely not the API key error otherwise I would get unauthorized message.

I have seen some examples where PUT was used instead of POST, so I am not sure if what I am doing for POST here is right or not. Kindly help me out.

```
IEnumerator POSTURL()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("ID", "Lemon");

        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post("website_url", form))
        {
            request.SetRequestHeader("api-key", KEY);
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(request.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
{
    "ID": "Orange",
    "Category": "Fruits",
}
```

Comment: Was your api call successfull when using "PUT"? You should read up on HTTP Statuscodes and their meaning. 405 specifically states that apperantly a Post is not allowed here and the api expects a different http verb.

Comment: What URL are you using? In place of "website_url" there should be valid URL that can process such request, are you sure it is a correct URL that can handle such request?

Comment: @Pio Yes even on the website where my JSON is, it is mentioned as "Put" to manually input the data. But I do not know how to use WWWForm with HTTP Put, since it uses byte if I am not wrong.

Comment: @IvanG yes I am aware of that but I think the problem is with POST/PUT. I must change the code to use HTTP Put. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59903701/7111561)? Maybe enconding is the issue?

Comment: I think the error then is pretty clear. POST not accepted by api, but PUT is. If possible try to find an example by the api how to do a put against that endpoint.

Comment: Also for `PUT` you could try `var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"ID\":\"Orange\",\"Category\":\"Fruits\"}");` and `using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Put("website_url", data))` see [`UnityWebRequest.Put`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Put.html)

Comment: @derHugo Ahh okay, it got a little more complicated :D I want to replace the value of ID to ```Lemon``` so why should I be retrieving the data first? I mean I may not even know if the data is same or changed.

Comment: @jay.mila then fill in `Lemon` instead? ^^

Comment: @derHugo could you please integrate what you understood in my code please. I think I am losing my mind here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still just a guess but easier to explain what I mean here ^^

You probably have to use [`UnityWebRequest.Put`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Put.html)

```
// You could pass these as parameters dynmically
IEnumerator POSTURL(string id, string category)
{
    // This is string interpolation and will dynamically fill in the 
    // id and category value
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{\"ID\":\"{id}\",\"Category\":\"{category}\"}}");

    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put("website_url", data))
    {
        request.SetRequestHeader("api-key", KEY);

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or as mentioned before you might also be able to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870055/how-to-get-the-json-content-of-a-http-post-request/59903701#59903701) and use `Post` but without a form but directly using raw data

> ```
> var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{\"ID\":\"{id}\",\"Category\":\"{category}\"}}");
> UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, "");
>
> // Fix: Add upload handler and pass json as bytes array
> webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(data);
>
> webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
> yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
> ```

Comment: I am sure this is definitely the right answer. Just that I was getting a syntax error at ```Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{\"ID\":\"{id}\",\"Category\":\"{category}\"}");``` I fixed it by ```"$```

Comment: Fixed that (only on smartphone but you have to escape `{` with `{{` when using string interpolation ^^), please try again

Comment: Thanks :) The issue now is ```HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type``` error. The example of JSON I posted here was a short one but I have a huge JSON data. I guess I must import them all in order to change the data of one ID?

Comment: @jay.mila this depends a lot on how your server is build and what it expects ... have you tried to set `webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: yes i tried and then I get ```HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request```. I shall take a look why this is happening but thank you for your solution :)

Comment: it is not working :/ I shall post it as a new question.