# Using HTTP Put json in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, django-rest-framework, http-get

I am using `UnityWebRequest` to update (PUT) Raw JSON on the server. Unfortunately I get the error `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed`. I am assuming that I am not Encoding it correctly. What could be the issue here?
This is a follow up question asked by my colleague: [HTTP Method Not Allowed in REST API Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101302/http-method-not-allowed-in-rest-api-post)

We have tried to encode it in different ways as given below in the script. Unfortunately it does not work.
We have this JSON online and to enter data (PUT), it is a must to have the name and address fields as non-empty.

```
IEnumerator Post()
    {
        byte[] myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{'name': 'User01', 'address':{'raw':'MountFiji'}}");
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put("website_of_the_user", myData);
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
 
        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("Upload complete!");
        }
    }
```

```
{
    "name": "",
    "address": {
        "raw": ""
    }
}
```

The webpage where we have our API has following properties:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Does connection work with Postman?  Most of the time issues like this Postman works and c# does not work.  The c# default headers are not the same as Postman.  So best way of solving is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the headers in C# and Postman.  Then make c# headers look like Postman.  Also check version of TLS being used and make sure same version os being used.

Comment: @jdweng no we have tried it. It does not work with POST either.

Comment: do you have access to the back-end code (server code)? I guessing there is nothing wrong with your code but the server fails processing your request.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen unfortunately no, we do not have it. Are you sure it could be backend code problem? Is there nothing wrong with the way we are encoding it?

Comment: Do you have any sample code that works?  Every server is different and you either need a working application, good documentation that give proper format of message, or source of Server code so you can debug.

Comment: @Amar.linsila your code looks fine to me, server accepts json and you provide json, maybe try "" instead of '' when defining your json properties (you can escape in a string using \" )

Comment: @JochemVanHespen sorry i don't know what you mean. Could you please show it to me in my JSON code?

Comment: Uhm no I the names and values of the json properties, you use single quotes try to use double for those (just a guess though)

Comment: Like so: {"name": "User01", "address":{"raw":"MountFiji"}}"

Answer (score 4):

I got it working. If anyone in future faces this problem, then the solution is simpler than you think. The problem was the JSON format code, it is important to give `\` since the data is a string. Here is the complete code:

```
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put(URL_01, "{\"name\":\"user_01\",\"address\":{\"raw\":\"MountFiji\"}}");
            www.SetRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            }
```