# how to post my data using UnityWebRequest post api call

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, unitywebrequest

Here is my API request

```
public IEnumerator Login(string bodyJsonString)
{
    Debug.Log(bodyJsonString);

    UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Post("localhost:3000/login", bodyJsonString);
    req.SetRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    yield return req.SendWebRequest();
    if (req.isNetworkError || req.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(req.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }

}
```

It returns an error status code 500 and on the server returns an error Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0","severity

Here is my Coroutine Call

```
public void submitLogin()
{

    _username = userInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    _password = passwordInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;

    Debug.Log("username" + _username);
    Debug.Log("password" + _password);

    string body = "{'username':'" + _username + "','password','" + _password + "'}";

    //API Call
    authChexi = new Auth();
    StartCoroutine(authChexi.Login(body));
}
```

Let me know if you have ideas on how to deal with my form body. Thanks

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878957/7111561 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59405175/7111561

Comment: Also I hope you escape this somehow ... what if a user types in a `'` or `}` as part of the username or in particular the password?

Comment: Why are you manually building up a JSON string? That's almost certainly where your issue is. Use Unity's built-in JSON serializer to do that instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I have updated my function. I did some digging and finally solved it. My mistake was indeed manually building up a JSON. So here is my solution.

```
public void submitLogin()
{

    _username = userInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    _password = passwordInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;

    //API Call
    authChexi = new Auth();
    StartCoroutine(authChexi.Login(_username, _password));
}
```

Created a class userdata for my json object

```
public class UserData 
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
    public string email;
}
```

And call the API

```
public IEnumerator Login(string username, string password)
{
    //@TODO: call API login
    // Store Token
    // Add Token to headers

    var user = new UserData();
    user.username = username;
    user.password = password;

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);

    var req = new UnityWebRequest("localhost:3000/login", "POST");
    byte[] jsonToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
    req.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonToSend);
    req.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    req.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    //Send the request then wait here until it returns
    yield return req.SendWebRequest();

    if (req.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + req.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + req.downloadHandler.text);
    }

}
```

And now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a **valid JSON string in the request**. You should provide **double quotes instead of single quotes** for each attributes with the help of the escape character ("").

Try to change the methods as follows,

```
public IEnumerator Login(string bodyJsonString)
{
    UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest("localhost:3000/login", "POST");
    byte[] data = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(data);  // important
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //important

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request.isNetworkError)  // 
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + request.error);
    else
        Debug.Log("Received: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
}

public void submitLogin()
{

    _username = userInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    _password = passwordInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;

    Debug.Log("username" + _username);
    Debug.Log("password" + _password);

    string body = "{\"username\":\"" + _username + "\",\"password\":\"" + _password + "\"}"; //important

    //API Call
    authChexi = new Auth();
    StartCoroutine(authChexi.Login(body));
}
```